# I can't get copy_from_user to work properly

Tags: linux-kernel

I am very new in kernel coding. My question might seem very silly but I have spent quite amount of time and couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.
here is my code. It seems like nothing gets copied to buff and when I printk result_of_cfu, it is 8 meaning 8 bytes are not copied.
what am I doing wrong here?

```
asmlinkage long sys_take_stat(struct array_stats *stats, long data[],long size){
unsigned long result_of_cfu = 0;
int counter = 0;
for(counter = 0;counter<size;size++){
   long buff = 0;
   long current_data = data[counter];
   result_of_cfu = copy_from_user(&buff,&current_data,sizeof(current_data));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use *copy_from_user* instead of dereferencing *data* pointer:

```
...
for(counter = 0;counter<size;size++){
    long buff;
    result_of_cfu = copy_from_user(&buf, data + counter, sizeof(*data));
}
```